# Import .SQLite file in an android Activity (Android SQLite Database)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have successfully Create a database program.
Basically i am dealing with a little complex database, So need to make database in SQLITE MANAGER and Import/link that Database with my android code.
Please suggest me Tutorial to do this. Or any other Piece of code that help me.
Thanks

here Is my code for database now i want to Import mYdataBase.sqlite file in that.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: do you need a sample to use the database into your application?

Comment: well you can take a look at my answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want import your database file from asset folder than below code can help you

```
void checkDB() throws Exception {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase dbe = SQLiteDatabase
                    .openDatabase(
                            "/data/data/com.yourpackagename/databases/yourfile.sqlite",
                            null, 0);
            Log.d("opendb", "EXIST");
            dbe.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(
                    "/data/data/com.yourpackagename/databases/yourfile.sqlite");
            byte[] b = new byte[100];

            int r;
            InputStream is = am.open("yourfile.sqlite");
            while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, r);
            }
            Log.i("DATABASE_HELPER", "Copying the database ");
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html.
This a sample for using the database in your application.  hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks; But its not what i really wants.
i have a database file (*.sqlite) which i create in SQLITE MANAGER, Now i need to connect that database with my android code

Comment: well take a look at Hardik Nadiyapara's answer. I think that's the one you need

Comment: no problems. Even i got to know a new concept after this thread. Thanks to you too